# Mongodb in array query wont get any result

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Okay, so im getting all convensations with the following query:

```
return convensations.findOne({}).lean().then(function (convensations) {
console.log(convensations);
});
```

that would results in the following:

```
{ _id: 598dd4458b08b727dc53d4a6,
  initiateduser: 'spillinfo',
  gang: false,
  global: false,
  members: [ 'spillinfo', '59312d2b329b7535b07e273c' ],
  name: 'no name',
  __v: 0 }
```

**thats totally fine, but when i do**

```
var userid = "59312d2b329b7535b07e273c";
      return convensations.find({members: userid}).lean().then(function (convensations) {
console.log(convensations);
});
```

it wont get me any results, why is that?

what im i doing wrong to check if the userid is within the members array?

UPDATE EDIT:

DB schema:

```
new Schema({
    initiateduser : String,
    name: {type:String, default: 'no name'},
    members: { type: Array, default: []},
    time: Number,
    global: { type: Boolean, default: false},
    gang: { type: Boolean, default: false},

});
```

and example of inserting / creating new:

```
   var conv = new convensations();
            conv.members = [userid, user2];
            conv.initiateduser = userid;
            conv.save(function (err,room) {
```

edit2:

some debug from query:

```
getting convensations with userid 59312d2b329b7535b07e273c
Mongoose: convensations.find({ members: ObjectId("59312d2b329b7535b07e273c") }, { fields: {} })
convensations: 0
```

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: Did you saved ObjectId inside `memebers` array. pls check database content

Comment: database content looks okay. Updated @Sajeetharan with schema.

Comment: It looks fine no issues

Comment: Can you try this : `find({members: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid)})`

Comment: Try to [enable profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/): `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` and check what query is actually being executed.

Comment: @AlexBlex didnt try that, but debugged the mongoose now. updated with the acual query.

Comment: change your schema and try as  members: { type: [string], default: []},

Comment: Somewhy mongoose converted the string to object id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your schema as,

```
new Schema({
    initiateduser : String,
    name: {type:String, default: 'no name'},
    members: { type: [String], default: []},
    time: Number,
    global: { type: Boolean, default: false},
    gang: { type: Boolean, default: false},

});
```

Comment: thanks. btw, do u know any reason i cant use $nin the members?r: $nin needs an array

Comment: No you can do it